# Scrapy 0 pages crawled but no visible issue?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub, portia

I used Portia to create a spider and then downloaded it as scrapy project. The spider runs fine but it says in the logs: Scrapy Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min) and also nothing get's saved. However, it also shows all the pages crawled with 200 response, then shows the bytes of data at the end..

**Spider Code**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Identity
from scrapy.spiders import Rule

from ..utils.spiders import BasePortiaSpider
from ..utils.starturls import FeedGenerator, FragmentGenerator
from ..utils.processors import Item, Field, Text, Number, Price, Date, Url, Image, Regex
from ..items import PortiaItem, AllProductsBooksToScrapeSandboxItem


class BooksToscrape(BasePortiaSpider):
    name = "books.toscrape.com"
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = [{'fragments': [{'valid': True,
                                  'type': 'fixed',
                                  'value': 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-'},
                                 {'valid': True,
                                  'type': 'range',
                                  'value': '1-50'},
                                 {'valid': True,
                                  'type': 'fixed',
                                  'value': '.html'}],
                   'type': 'generated',
                   'url': 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-[1-50].html'}]
    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=(),
                deny=('.*')
            ),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        )
    ]
    items = [
        [
            Item(
                AllProductsBooksToScrapeSandboxItem, None, '.product_pod', [
                    Field(
                        'title', 'h3 > a::attr(title)', []), Field(
                        'price', '.product_price > .price_color *::text', [])])]]
```

**Pipeline Code**
I added openSpider and closeSpider functions to write the items to json lines upon crawling and I think it works because jl file gets created.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import json

class TesterPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('items.jl', 'w')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

**Settings Code**
Enabled pipeline in settings too for pipeline to work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for Tester project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'Tester'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['Tester.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Tester.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'Tester (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'Tester.middlewares.TesterSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'Tester.middlewares.TesterDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'Tester.pipelines.TesterPipeline': 300,
}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

When I run the spider, the following ***log*** is created:

```
(scrape) C:\Users\da74\Desktop\tester>scrapy crawl books.toscrape.com
2018-07-24 12:18:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: Tester)
2018-07-24 12:18:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.2.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.5.0, Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2018-07-24 12:18:15 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'Tester', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Tester.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Tester.spiders']}
2018-07-24 12:18:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['Tester.pipelines.TesterPipeline']
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-7.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-4.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-3.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-9.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-5.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-8.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-6.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-10.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-12.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-11.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-14.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-15.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-16.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-17.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-13.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-18.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-19.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-21.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-20.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-22.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-23.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-25.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-24.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-26.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-27.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-32.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-29.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-30.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-33.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-28.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-31.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-34.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-35.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-36.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-39.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-40.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-38.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-41.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-37.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-42.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-43.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-44.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-47.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-45.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-46.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-48.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-49.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-50.html> (referer: None)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 12168,
 'downloader/request_count': 51,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 51,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 299913,
 'downloader/response_count': 51,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 50,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 24, 4, 18, 18, 598891),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 52,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 51,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 50,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 50,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 50,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 50,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 24, 4, 18, 16, 208142)}
2018-07-24 12:18:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I don't understand why it isn't gathering items. I says first that 0 items crawled and then shows 200 success response for pages..
Please if anyone has any idea what to try to make it crawl will be helpful. 
Thankyou

Comment: is it work without pipeline?

Comment: I don't see the parse -> yield in your code, did you miss something?

Comment: thanks for reply. I generated the spider through Portia.

Comment: no it doesn't work without pipelines too. same result even if I didn't edit anything..Maybe something wrong with Portia..